# (SOS) -bash: fork: Not enough space on every command

Tags: fork

I'm running SmartOS in a SmartOS Zone, and now any bash command return me

```
-bash: fork: Not enough space
```

Works only `ulimit`

How to fix it?

Comment: You've run out of virtual memory.

Comment: @MichaelHomer so I need to reboot it? or what?

Comment: @mikeserv no, I just reloaded nginx configuration. how can I kill nginx without working killall?

Comment: @mikeserv also, `exec bash` don't do anything

Comment: @mikeserv f_ck. it's just disconnected me.

Comment: im probably way off - the real clue there - which i missed - is `fork` - thats system-wide - probably nothing to do with `bash`. it just reminded me of a  question which did. reboot. just give up,

Comment: @mikeserv it's kick me from ssh, and reconnected after a minute. I just kill all nginx processes with htop and it's ok

Comment: Just to point out, `killall` will kill all active processes. You probably meant `pkill`. See: https://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/The+Linux-to-SmartOS+Cheat+Sheet

Answer (score -1):

It means your swap area has run out. either increase swap size or find the application that consumes all the swap space and `kill -9` it.

you can also increase or add more swap space.